# Ambiguous method overloading for method de.hybris.platform.tx.DefaultTransaction#execute

Tags: groovy, sap-commerce-cloud

We have a cronjob that is calling a groovy script. The goal of the script is to change the value of a product property depending on several conditions. When we run the cronjob, specifically the groovy script, we get below error. I also inserted the groovy script that is receiving the error. I don't remember when this issue occurred because it was working last year 4th quarter.

Error:

```
Script execution has failed [reason: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method de.hybris.platform.tx.DefaultTransaction#execute.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [class UpdateWorker$_call_closure1] due to overlapping prototypes between:
    [interface de.hybris.platform.tx.TransactionBody]
    [interface de.hybris.platform.tx.TransactionBody$GenericTransactionBody]]
```

Groovy script:

```
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.model.ModelService
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.i18n.CommonI18NService
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.FlexibleSearchQuery
import java.util.stream.Collectors
import de.hybris.platform.core.model.enumeration.EnumerationValueModel
import com.SubstitutionModel
import de.hybris.platform.tx.Transaction
import groovy.time.TimeCategory
import groovy.time.TimeDuration
import java.util.Date
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.interceptor.impl.InterceptorExecutionPolicy
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.session.SessionExecutionBody
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.interceptor.impl.InterceptorExecutionPolicy.InterceptorType
import java.util.List
import java.util.concurrent.Callable
import de.hybris.platform.core.Registry
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import de.hybris.platform.core.TenantAwareThreadFactory
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.session.SessionService
import de.hybris.platform.catalog.CatalogVersionService
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.impl.DefaultFlexibleSearchService
def COMMIT_PACE = 1000
def TOTAL_THREADS = 10
def log = Logger.getLogger('updateProductSubstitutionScript');

def query = /select distinct {p.pk} from {Product as p JOIN CatalogVersion as cv ON  {p.catalogVersion} = {cv.PK}} where ({p.triggerSubstitutionCronjob} = 1 OR {p.substitutionIndicator} IS NULL OR {p.substitutionCode} IS NULL) and {cv.version} = 'Online'/

class UpdateWorker implements Callable {
  
    // Product substitution enum
    def subCodeNoEntry = /0/
    def subCodeOneEntry = /1/
    def subCodeMoreEntriesNoConditionalNotes = /2/
    def subCodeMoreEntriesWithConditionalNotes = /3/
  
    def subIndicatorBoth = /B/
    def subIndicatorForward = /F/
    def subIndicatorPrevious = /P/
    def subIndicatorEmpty = /N/
  

    def catalogVersionService

    def newCv

    List lines

    def privateLogger

    def sessionService

    def modelService

    def flexibleSearchService

    def params = ImmutableMap.of(InterceptorExecutionPolicy.DISABLED_UNIQUE_ATTRIBUTE_VALIDATOR_FOR_ITEM_TYPES, ImmutableSet.of('Product','Substitution'));

    public UpdateWorker(List linesToProcess, Logger logger, SessionService sessionService, ModelService modelService, CatalogVersionService catalogVersionService, DefaultFlexibleSearchService flexibleSearchService){
        lines = linesToProcess
        privateLogger = logger
        this.sessionService = sessionService
        this.modelService = modelService
        this.catalogVersionService = catalogVersionService
        this.flexibleSearchService = flexibleSearchService
    }

    def String call() {
        def startThread = new Date()
        privateLogger.info('IsNested transaction: ' + Transaction.current().isNested())
        Transaction.current().execute(
            {
                lines.each { line ->
                    sessionService.executeInLocalViewWithParams(params, new SessionExecutionBody(){ public void executeWithoutResult(){
                            def queryForSubstitution = /select distinct {s.pk} from {Substitution as s} where ({s.partForSubstitutionCode} = ?productPk or {s.skuReplacementCode} = ?productPk) and {s.partForSubstitutionCode} is not null and {s.skuReplacementCode} is not null/
                            def productPk = line.getCode();
                            def queryParams = [:];
                            queryParams.put('productPk', productPk);
                            final FlexibleSearchQuery fsQuery = new FlexibleSearchQuery(queryForSubstitution, queryParams);
                            
                            def substitutions = flexibleSearchService.search(fsQuery).getResult();
                            
                            if(substitutions.size() == 0)
                            {
                                line.setSubstitutionCode(subCodeNoEntry);
                                line.setSubstitutionIndicator(subIndicatorEmpty);
                            }
                            else{
                                def subFromList = [];
                                def subToList = [];
                                //Split into 2 list
                                for(SubstitutionModel substitution : substitutions)
                                {
                                    //These fields are mandatories during hotfolder process
                                    //Anyway are not mandatories in hybris sistem, this null check avoid to abort cronjob
                                    if(substitution.getPartForSubstitutionCode() != null && substitution.getSkuReplacementCode() != null)
                                    {
                                        if(substitution.getPartForSubstitutionCode() == productPk) {
                                            subFromList.add(substitution)
                                        } else {
                                            subToList.add(substitution)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                //Calculate substitution code
                                def substitutionCode;
                            
                                if(subFromList.size() == 0){
                                    substitutionCode = subCodeNoEntry
                                }
                                else if(subFromList.size() == 1){
                                    if(subFromList.get(0).getConditionalNotes() != null && !subFromList.get(0).getConditionalNotes().isEmpty())
                                    {
                                        substitutionCode = subCodeMoreEntriesWithConditionalNotes
                                    }   
                                    else{
                                        substitutionCode = subCodeOneEntry
                                    }   
                                }
                                else{
                                    substitutionCode = subCodeMoreEntriesNoConditionalNotes
                                    for(SubstitutionModel substitution : substitutions)
                                    {
                                        if(substitution.getConditionalNotes() != null && !substitution.getConditionalNotes().isEmpty()){
                                            substitutionCode = subCodeMoreEntriesWithConditionalNotes
                                            break
                                        }
                                    }               
                                }
                                line.setSubstitutionCode(substitutionCode)
                                
                                //Calculate substitution indicator
                                def substitutionIndicator;
                            
                                if(subFromList.size() > 0 && subToList.size() > 0){
                                    substitutionIndicator = subIndicatorBoth
                                }
                                else if (subFromList.size() > 0 && subToList.size() == 0){
                                    substitutionIndicator = subIndicatorForward
                                }
                                else if (subFromList.size() == 0 && subToList.size() > 0){
                                    substitutionIndicator = subIndicatorPrevious
                                }
                                line.setSubstitutionIndicator(substitutionIndicator) 
                            }   
                            line.setTriggerSubstitutionCronjob(false)
                            modelService.save(line)                         
                                            
                    }})
                }
            }
        )
        def stopThread = new Date()
        def TimeDuration td = TimeCategory.minus( stopThread, startThread )
        privateLogger.info('Sanitized ' + lines.size() + ' elements in' + td)
        return 'Sanitized ' + lines.size() + ' elements in' + td
    }
}

defaultFlexibleSearchService = spring.getBean('defaultFlexibleSearchService')



final FlexibleSearchQuery fsQuery = new FlexibleSearchQuery(query)
fsQuery.setStart(0)
fsQuery.setCount(COMMIT_PACE*TOTAL_THREADS)


threadFactory = new TenantAwareThreadFactory(Registry.currentTenant, Registry.currentTenant.activeSession)

executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(TOTAL_THREADS,threadFactory)

boolean morelines = true
count = 0
def startMain = new Date()
//while(modelines && count<3){
while(morelines){
    start = new Date()
    result = flexibleSearchService.search(fsQuery)
    if (result.getCount()==0){
        log.info('No more lines to move')
        morelines=false
    }
    else{
        resultList = result.getResult()
        List workers = new ArrayList();
        resultsForWorker = resultList.collate(COMMIT_PACE)
        resultsForWorker.each{
            linesForWorker -> log.info('Lines to move for worker: ' + linesForWorker.size())
            workers.add(new UpdateWorker(linesForWorker, log, sessionService, modelService, catalogVersionService, defaultFlexibleSearchService))
        }
        List durationsFuture = executorService.invokeAll(workers)
        durationsFuture.each{ durationFuture ->
            log.info('Retrieved worker duration: ' + durationFuture.get())
        }
        count++
    }
    modelService.detachAll();
}
def stopMain = new Date()
def TimeDuration overallTd = TimeCategory.minus( stopMain, startMain )
log.info('Overall sanitization process duration: ' + overallTd)

executorService.shutdown()
```

Comment: which hybris version are you using?

additionally you need to explicitly tell  which execute method you want to execute either from TransactionBody or GenericTransactionBody so please cast explicitly .

Comment: We are using version 2211. Let's say I want TransactionBody. How will it look like in my script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`execute() method should have explicit type to be executed`

and the code should be like this.

```
def String call() {
        def startThread = new Date()
        privateLogger.info('IsNested transaction: ' + Transaction.current().isNested())
        Transaction.current().execute(
            { TransactionBody txBody ->
                lines.each { line ->
                    sessionService.executeInLocalViewWithParams(params, new SessionExecutionBody(){ public void executeWithoutResult(){
                    //Rest code should be as same
            }
        as TransactionBody)
        def stopThread = new Date()
        def TimeDuration td = TimeCategory.minus( stopThread, startThread )
        privateLogger.info('Sanitized ' + lines.size() + ' elements in' + td)
        return 'Sanitized ' + lines.size() + ' elements in' + td
    }
}
```